# Pytorch: backwards differentiation on a function of a Hessian: "

Tags: pytorch

I just finished debugging a crazy error in my pytorch code, so I thought I'd share my experience.

As a minimal example, here's some code that crashes:

```
import torch
ts = torch.tensor
t = ts([i+.5 for i in range(5)], requires_grad=True) #some tensor
f = torch.sum(t**3) #some function of t
[lg] = torch.autograd.grad(f,t,create_graph=True,retain_graph=True) #the gradient of f wrt t
[lgg] = torch.autograd.grad(lg[1],t,create_graph=True,retain_graph=True) #one row of the Hessian of f wrt t
lgg2 = lgg.contiguous().view(-1)
lgg3 = torch.zeros(6,6,requires_grad=True) #if we were calculating the full Hessian, it would be a matrix...
lgg3[1,1:].add_(lgg2.type_as(lgg3)) #...and we'd fill it in row by row 
l2 = torch.sum(lgg3) #a loss that's a function of the Hessian
l2.backward() #we want the gradient of that loss
print(t.grad)
print(lgg3.requires_grad)
```

This gives the error:

```
RuntimeError: leaf variable has been moved into the graph interior
```

How to fix it? I will give you the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `requires_grad` when creating lgg3. lgg3 will still have it set to `True` by the end of this code but this stops the error. It's voodoo but it works.

```
import torch
ts = torch.tensor
t = ts([i+.5 for i in range(5)], requires_grad=True) #some tensor
f = torch.sum(t**3) #some function of t
[lg] = torch.autograd.grad(f,t,create_graph=True,retain_graph=True) #the gradient of f wrt t
[lgg] = torch.autograd.grad(lg[1],t,create_graph=True,retain_graph=True) #one row of the Hessian of f wrt t
lgg2 = lgg.contiguous().view(-1)
lgg3 = torch.zeros(6,6) #if we were calculating the full Hessian, it would be a matrix...
lgg3[1,1:].add_(lgg2.type_as(lgg3)) #...and we'd fill it in row by row 
l2 = torch.sum(lgg3) #a loss that's a function of the Hessian
l2.backward() #we want the gradient of that loss
print(t.grad)
print(lgg3.requires_grad) #look, it's True.
```